# Home page top slider how to show in the category page?

Tags: magento-1.8

My home page is 1column.phtml and my category page is 2columns-right.phtml. In home page there is a featured slider which is in the path template\eternal\homeslider\slideshow.phtml but I have to show this slider in the category page which is 2columns-right.phtml. How can I do this.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call featured slider block/phtml in 2columns-right.phtml using check the following condition of category page.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
if($controller == 'catalog_category_view){
    //call your block of slider
}
```

It will show the slider only in category page.